# What are the possible penalties in portuguese law for kidnapping or false imprisonment?

Tags: criminal-law, sentencing, portugal, kidnapping

Presumably there are custodial sentences applicable, what is the minimum and maximum length?

Comment: This question provides all details necessary to answer it, place, charge, and punishment length.

Comment: @User37849012643, did somebody suggest otherwise?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, that much was clear, and thank you. I was just confused as to the context, and was wondering if perhaps there might've been a comment before yours that was now deleted.

Comment: But now I understand. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The potential sentences are set forth in the [Penal Code of Portugal](http://europam.eu/data/mechanisms/PF/PF%20Laws/Portugal/Portugal_criminal%20code_1982_amended2015_por.pdf) at Articles 153 to 162. The statute for each offense sets forth a maximum penalty. The most serious offense of this type is punishable by up to 16 years in prison.

There is not always a minimum penalty and sentencing alternatives earlier in the Penal Code undermine the minimum sentences set forth in the selected cases where they are present so that they don't really mean what they appear to mean. So, it is not informative to try to list minimum penalties.